# "The JSON request was too large to be deserialized" MVC KnockoutJs

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I've been scrapping the threads for an answer in similar threads with no luck.

I am using knockoutJS to pass the information back from my partial view and I am getting the "The JSON request was too large to be deserialized".

I have done the   " " fix but this isn't helping.

My page has quiet a bit of information to pass back in the forms of lists,  and I believe this is why I am getting the errors on this page and not others where I am using  knockout.

I have read that I can build my own serializer but that in itself can lead to more problems.

Would anyone be able to suggest alternatives?

One thing I was trying to find out is if I can stop passing back the whole lists and only pass back the selected values, but I can't seem to find any more information on this .

TIA

Comment: Hi Ross, welcome to SO.  Please can you post the code so that the problem can be reproduced?

Answer (score 6):

I added the key below and it worked for me.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

This *may* be by design.... to protect the site from DoS attacks or time-out conditions

There is an **app** setting for `MaxJsonDeserializerMembers` which you may be able to increase, but would need to be done with care: [...JSON payload members fails with an exception](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2661403/an-asp.net-request-that-has-lots-of-form-keys,-files,-or-json-payload-members-fails-with-an-exception)

What I have done in the past is to either break up the forms into (collapsible) sections and doing AJAX posts by group, or spreading the form out over multiple pages. Front end users generally will be happier if anything as they don't see the gazillion fields at once.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error message when I returned partial view via ajax call. It turned out that the problem was in the partial - "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object".

```
@User.Address.Address1
```

The "Address" was null. Fixed that by doing some checks

```
@if(User.Address != null){
   @User.Address.Address1
}
```